# How to access panel document in Firefox extension (after calling webservice)?

Tags: firefox-addon

I defined a html filed for the content of my panel, which is in data folder.

```
var popupPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("main.html")
});
```

I'm trying to access the DOM of this document, from a javascript, which is in lib folder. Seems to be not possible, since document variable is undefined.

Then I followed one of the sample add ons, where there's html and javascript in the data folder, and this javascript accesses the DOM of the html. I tried to follow this example, but differently than in this sample, I also have to call a webservice, and modify the DOM using the response. I found that I can't call webservices from the javascripts stored in data folder.

I read something about implementing communication between files in lib and data folder - but this is a very simple use case and I hope that there's a simpler solution, like, just putting the workflow in a single JS file :D (In Chrome it's possible!).

Note: I'm not asking how to call the webservice, already got that working. My only problem is how do I do that + access the DOM on the response.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [the SDK panel documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html):

> **You can't directly access your panel's content from your main add-on
>   code.** To access the panel's content, you need to load a script into
>   the panel. In the SDK these scripts are called "content scripts"
>   because they're explicitly used for interacting with web content.
>
> While content scripts can access the content they're attached to, they
>   can't use the SDK's APIs. **So implementing a complete solution usually
>   means you have to send messages between the content script and the
>   main add-on code.**